# POST Ajax запрос не работает

Tags: ajax, php

Вроде всё делаю верно, но при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит. Приём ПОСТА стоит, но его нет смысла писать.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function send()
{
var be = $('#be').val();
var pe = $('#pe').val();
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/?page=send",
            data: "be="+be+"&pe="+pe,
            }
    });

}
</script>

<form action="">
<input id="be" type="text" name="be">
<input id="pe" type="hidden" name="pe" value="1">
</form>

 <input type="button" onclick="send();" value="Отправить" />
```

Comment: лишняя } в $.ajax.

научитесь пользоваться консолью. да и документацию к jquery почитать будет не лишним, например, про serialize, ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="/?page=send" method="post" id="myform">
    <input id="be" type="text" name="be" />
    <input id="pe" type="hidden" name="pe" value="1" />
    <input type="button" value="Отправить" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">//<[!CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').on('submit', function(e){
        var _self = $(this);
       $.ajax({
            type: _self.attr('method'),
            url: _self.attr('action'),
            data: _self.serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
//]]></script>
```

Comment: Перекракозябрили до безобразия. Это не подходит к моим дальнейшим действиям. Нельзя было исправить ошибки в моём коде?

Comment: Тогда просто уберите лишнюю скобку, как вам подсказали выше, и продолжайте писать без моего **безобразия и кракозябров**

Comment: @Rammsteinik, пойду отнесу этот код в галерею безобразительного искусства, пусть народ дивится, как безобразительно можно написать безобразескрипт.